# Typescript Object type to Array type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What is the correct way to transform an object type to an array of objects, each one containing one key of the object ?

For instance I want to transform

```
type MyObjectType = {
    foo: number,
    bar: string
}
```

into

```
type MyObjectArrayType = { key: 'foo', value: number} | { key: 'bar', value: string}
```

so that I can do

```
const objects: MyObjectArrayType[] = [{key: 'foo', value: 2}, {key: 'bar', value: 'baz'}]
```

I was thinking about something like

```
type MyObjectArrayType<K extends keyof MyObjectType> = { value: MyObjectType[K], key: K }
```

but can't get it to work like I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to generate each member of the union (for each property) and the use an index type to get all the value types in the mapped type.

```
type MyObjectType = {
    foo: number,
    bar: string
}

type PropUnion<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: { value: T[K], key: K }
}[keyof T]

type MyObjectArrayType = PropUnion<MyObjectType>;
const objects: MyObjectArrayType[] = [{key: 'foo', value: 2}, {key: 'bar', value: 'baz'}]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=90&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVhAxsAKuaBeKA3gFBSlQBmA9pQFxQB2ArgLaIQBOANCWYgIbs6AZ2DsAlvQDmRAL5EioSFAAK7SmACq9MZXoAeTAD4o+YqQDaAaSgSoAawghK5KJgC6dAlABufADaMEHSYVm6c9o501nIy5g5OLu7yitBwSKgYAILs7Hwg2Er4qupaOvppKOhYOIYA3ERouiJQlJUYQnQVGcDZufk45m4mUOYE8XQA5FSUE+G+AUFQAEwy4WORUBP87LM+-oGT-ABeEzJuREA)

Comment: Would it be simple in case the object's members are all of the same type ?